# Register a BHO through an NSIS installer

Tags: com, nsis, bho

I have an IE BHO which I was packaging through the Visual Studio setup and deployment project. I now want to the package it through an NSIS installer.

My BHO was registering in the following way:

```
    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void Register(Type t)
    {
        string guid = t.GUID.ToString("B");

        RegistryKey rkClass = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(@"CLSID\"+guid );
        RegistryKey rkCat = rkClass.CreateSubKey("Implemented Categories");

        string name = toolbarName;
        string help = toolbarHelpText;

        rkClass.SetValue(null, name );
        rkClass.SetValue("MenuText", name );
        rkClass.SetValue("HelpText", help );

        if( 0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.Vertical) )
            rkCat.CreateSubKey("{00021493-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

        if( 0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.Horizontal) )
            rkCat.CreateSubKey("{00021494-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

        if( 0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.TaskbarToolBar) )
            rkCat.CreateSubKey("{00021492-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");

        if( 0 != (style & BandObjectStyle.ExplorerToolbar) )
            Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar").SetValue(guid,name);

    }
```

While this is taken care of by the msi installer that is made by VS, I want to know how can I do the same using NSIS?

Any help would be appreciated!

Kapil

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly call `regsvr32.exe` during both installation (to register) and removal (to unregister).

e.g. during installation:

```
Exec 'regsvr32.exe /s "$INSTDIR\your_bho.dll"'
```

...and during removal:

```
 Exec 'regsvr32.exe /s /u "$INSTDIR\your_bho.dll"'
```

...where `your_bho.dll` is the filename for your BHO. The `/s` flag, btw, inhibits the command from displaying a dialog to your end-user. `regsvr32.exe` is in the `system32` directory, so you don't need to worry about the path to it.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the [NSIS registry plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Registry_plug-in), which gives you plenty of useful helper functions.

And use [RegDLL](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ActiveX_Dll_Component_Register) for registering the DLL.